# How do I find the equation from an lm() function r?

Tags: r, lm, non-linear-regression

I am using the lm() to fit a curve to a set of data. Using the fitted model, I would like to find the equation so that I can apply it to my larger data set, however, I am unable to arrive at the correct equation.

I have used the lm() function function before for liner and multiple regressions and have successfully extracted the equation using the output of the model summary. In this case, I am unable to to calculate the function from my model outputs. The model I am using now is more complex and contains constants

Here is the data and sample code:

```
# Data
x <- c(18.212128, 23.453468, 30.275368, 18.721986, 22.831441, 12.624084, 13.572420,  9.564936,  4.282807, 13.042168, 12.032649, 13.082956, 13.144139, 11.247467, 10.074794, 14.123067,  8.830741, 10.380709, 10.054400,  6.444605,  3.936104,  2.590079,  2.834810, 16.111513, 12.399747, 10.186963, 15.397712,  3.324274, 13.123745,  8.698177, 27.960613,  5.455481,  6.373225,  3.263091,  6.842294,  7.013732, 16.373396, 34.661337, 35.608483)

y <- c(1.5740,  28.1570, 30.9710, 3.5450, 5.7480, 0.4950,  2.9810,   0.8400,   1.7500,  0.7165,   0.9920, 0.8065, 1.0680, 0.5640, 0.1430,  1.0605, 0.2745, 0.7750,  0.6750,  0.7800,   0.4050,   0.4035,   0.4210,   7.6080,   5.5820, 2.3250, 5.7760,  0.3125,   6.9100,  3.0575,  40.0450,   3.5900,   3.8050,   0.6435,   1.2600,   2.8100,  12.4200, 176.400, 128.8000)


# set variables
K = 1
a = -4
p= .34

# Create the model
model<- lm(K*(y+a)^p ~ x)

# Create predicted values 
model.predict <- exp(predict(model,list(Level=x))) 

# Print the Summary
summary(model)

# Plot 
plot_ly(x = x, y=y)%>%
  add_markers()%>%
  add_lines(x = x, y=model.predict)%>%
#add_lines(x = x.dummy, y=y.dummy)%>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = "Water Level (cm)"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Discharge")
  )
```

I am fairly happy with the fitted curve produced by this model. How do I use the outputs of the model to find the equation that allows me to calculate y based on x?

I have tried to find the function of y based on the model outputs

```
Call:
lm(formula = K * (y + a)^p ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
    -1.2304       0.1712
```

K*(y+a)^p = -1.23036  + 0.17123  * x

I then rearranged the equation:

y = ((-1.23036  + 0.17123  * x)/K)^(1/p) - a

But the resulting curves are not the same

Below is a visualization of the two curves:

```
x.dummy <- seq(from = 0, to = 40, by = 1)
y.dummy <-  ((-1.23036   + 0.17123 * x.dummy)/K)^(1/p) - a


plot_ly(x = x, y=y)%>%
  add_markers()%>%
  add_lines(x = x, y=model.predict)%>%
  add_lines(x = x.dummy, y=y.dummy)%>%
  layout(
    xaxis = list(title = "Water Level (cm)"),
    yaxis = list(title = "Discharge")
  )
```

[image: Plotted data and 2 fitted curves]

Comment: why are you surrounding your prediction in an `exp()` ? Your other equation doesn't do that, so that might be the difference

Comment: Seems like the second curve you produced is the right one.  One thing to note is that the transformation you apply `K*(y+a)^p` makes 28 of your 39 `y`-values `NaN`, so you're only using 11 points to fit the model.

Comment: Actually `y ~ x^2` != `y^0.5 ~ x` as the second function is not defined for `x < 0`. but you do an alike transform